# what is the difference between JdbcCursorItemReader and JdbcPagingItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to spring batch . Trying to understand the difference between  JdbcCursorItemReader and JdbcPagingItemReader with examples.

Comment: check link        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386642/spring-batch-which-itemreader-implementation-to-use-for-high-volume-low-laten

Comment: Thanks Mushahid Khan.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch: Which ItemReader implementation to use for high volume & low latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386642/spring-batch-which-itemreader-implementation-to-use-for-high-volume-low-laten)